# Alternative way for the torture chamber?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-peace-walker

I am stuck at the button mashing sequence at the beginning of Main Ops 20: Torture Chamber Escape.

To be precise, I broke a PS3 controller trying to do this, and still haven't seen the following of the mission.

So is there any way to bypass this?

Researching just tells me that I'm not fast enough and that I should try again. I'm now a bit reluctant to do this, after seeing the triangle button get dislodged.

Comment: You have two different game tags in here.  Which are you talking about?

Comment: @Frank: Of the HD version (PS3 Version) of MGS Peace Walker.

Comment: I really don't mean for this to be a rude question, but did you try just tapping the button? I have the xbox 360 version and was able to complete it with multiple taps instead of mashing the button however I know some ps3 controllers were more stable than others.

Comment: @ColeBusby: Yes, in fact, the two first part are feasible, but the third... I can try as fast as I can, I even tried with a pen, between the flat button and the design of the ps3 controller, I just got the ressort beneath the button so stressed that it broke...

Comment: Yeah, in that case I would look into attempting it with another controller because for me it took about an hour and I know I wore on my buttons as well.

Comment: @ColeBusby: Well, I ll search for turbo controler so : /

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do the hardest parts of tortures in all Metal Gear Series is not to tap the triangle button but to pass your finger over it. Is the way I manage to do the European Extreme torture scene in Substance (Sons Of Liberty).

You put the end of your shirt, or any piece of cloth, around the tip of your finger (I used index for SoL), and when the time comes you don't tap the button, you pass the tip of your finger back and forth over the triangle button; fingernail tend to end up doing the job not fingertips but it'll get you there.

I didn't do this in Peace Walker though (neither PSP nor HD), frankly I didn't need to.